# Updating pre-existing list to avoid O(n^2)

Tags: python, performance, list

I want to create a new function, `neighbor_trial(atomlist,trialatom)`, that will run in `O(n)` instead of `neighbor(atomlist)` (`O(n^2)` time). I can accomplish this by merely updating the results from a previous run of `neighbor(atomlist)`. `trialatom` is an atom that is moved, all other atoms in `atomlist` are not moved.

Background:

`atomlist` is a list of instances of the Atom class. An Atom object has a function `atom1.is_neighbor(atom2)` that checks if `atom2` is a nearest neighbor of `atom1`. If it is, `atom2` is added to `atom1.nrst`, a list. An atom can only have a maximum of 12, unique, nearest neighbors and cannot include itself.

Problem:

`neighbor` correctly updates everyone `atom`'s `nrst` list but it is slow (it must be rerun many times). However, `neighbor_trial` does not update correctly. Every `atom`'s `nrst` neighbor has to be checked to see if `trialatom` is now a neighbor, as well as recreate the `nrst` list of the `atom`'s whose `nrst` list is wiped.

```
def neighbor(atomlist): 
    cdef int i, j
    for atom in atomlist:  
        atom.nrst=[]   #Unnecessarily deletes every atom's nrst! 
    for i in range(len(atomlist)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(atomlist)):
            if atomlist[i].is_neighbour(atomlist[j]):
                atomlist[i].nrst.append(atomlist[j])
                atomlist[j].nrst.append(atomlist[i])

def neighbor_trial(atomlist,trialatom):
    cdef int i, j
    redoo_list=[]
    for atom in trialatom.nrst:
        atom.nrst=[]            #Only trialatom and its neighbours' nrst list are wiped!
        redoo_list.append(atom)
    trialatom.nrst = []
    redoo_list.append(trialatom)
    for i in range(len(atomlist)):
        for j in range(len(redoo_list)):
            if atomlist[i] != redoo_list[j]:
                if atomlist[i].is_neighbour(redoo_list[j]):
                    redoo_list[j].nrst.append(atomlist[i])
```

Comment: Can you make the naming consistent? There is `neighbor_trial` then `neighlist_trial`

Comment: `Every atom's nrst neighbor has to be checked to see if trialatom is now a neighbor`... maybe I'm mistaken, but you don't have to check *every* atom's *every* neighbor- you can just check every atom once. Since every atom is an instance, when you change it in one place, you change it everywhere (even when it occurs in lists)

Comment: For what it's worth, the fact that every atom can have an exact number of nearest neighbors does make the problem much more difficult, both programmatically and algorithmically. For one thing, `isneighbor` is not a symmetric relationship: it is possible for `atom1.is_neighbour(atom2) != atom2.is_neighbour(atom1)`. Thus, you can't just update all the new neighbors of `atom1`. Do you have any flexibility on that specification?

Comment: nhahtdh - sorry about that, they are the same. I can't edit though.

Comment: David Robinson - they don't have to have an exact number, just a maximum of 12. In fact they're allowed to temporarily have more than 12 nearest neighbors. Then the trial move is rejected.